# Loading a specific module as seperate chunk

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Using vuejs with webpack, I have entry point for main.js file. Here is the code of main.js

```
import x from 'xyz';
import y from 'yza';
import z from 'zab'; <--- Want this as separate chunk
...
...
..
new Vue(...)
..
```

It adding the chunks to index.html like

```
<script src="app.934acnad.js" />
```

Now I want to load

```
import z from 'zab';
```

as a separate chunk so it appears before the app, like this

```
<script src="z.adsfr90244.js" />
<script src="app.934acnad.js" />
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
// vue.config.js


module.exports =
{
  configureWebpack: (config) => 
  {
    config.optimization = {
      splitChunks:
      {
        automaticNameDelimiter: '_',
        chunks: 'all',
        cacheGroups:
        {
          default:
          {
                minChunks: 2,
                priority: -20,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
          vendor:
          {
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]zab[\\/]/,
            name(module)
            {
              // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
              // or node_modules/packageName
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]([^\\/]+)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `vendor_${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but its adding the scripts in this order => app.js, then vender.js then zab.js. I want to load zab.js first in index.html

Comment: This thread will help you - https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/481 You will probably have to write a custom ordering function.